# All menu items redirect to homepage .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, pligg

I have the following webpage in Pligg CMS under the following url

```
http://africafreak.com/
```

I don't know why but every Menu item redirects to the Main Page. Here is my `.htacess` file

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

What seems to be the problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try last line as `RewriteRule . index.php [L]`

Comment: @anubhava Still not working

Comment: Must be an issue with your Pligg installation. Your `.htaccess` is fine. Except remove the backslash from the first rule, and move `RewriteBase /` to its own line.